# Не ставится Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2008 на Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio

Всем хеллоу! Пытаюсь поставить MVS2008 рядом с MSV2017, и у меня ничего не выходит. Офиса нет, пакеты VC++2008 удалял, не помогает. Ошибка такая:[image: Ошибка установки VS2008]

Что делать? Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: а зачем Вам это

Comment: На Win CE делать приложения к примеру.

Comment: Visual Studio Code есть

Comment: Это редактор кода, а не IDE - _-

Comment: пусть редактор кода будет с подключенным компилятором